# Any Default Pass By Reference DataTypes in C++?

Tags: c++

I understand that unlike C# ( where class is passed by reference and struct is passed by default), both structure and class in C++ are passed by value into a method, unless it is explicitly modified to pass by reference.

i.e.,

```
// this is a method that passes by reference
void PassReferenceOp(MyClass &myclass, MyStruct &myStruct)
{
}



// this is a method that passes by value
void PassReferenceOp(MyClass myclass, MyStruct myStruct)
{
}
```

My question is, is it that there is no data structure, data types in C++ that passes into a method by reference? That no matter I am using `std::list`, `std::list::iterator`,`std::map`, or any data types I create, be it struct or class, all are pass by reference?

Comment: Keep in mind that C# by default passes references by value (for classes). It likely makes more sense to compare C++ references to C# `ref` and `out` parameters, and C++ pointers to C# "references" (again in case of C# classes, not structs)

Comment: Remember that C++ makes no distinction between "classes" and "structs" (both keywords declare classes) except for a minor implementation detail: default access of members and bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no default pass by reference types. Of course, there are references which are passed by value (most notably, smart pointers), the difference between which you could argue for a while.

Not that I see the importance. Adding an & is hardly the epitome of difficulty or time wastage.

Comment: what about `iterator`? I thought `iterator` is already a pointer, so one would just need to write void `PassByReference(List<int>::iterator iterator)`?

Comment: @Graviton: The `iterator` is still passed by value- even if that value is a pointer.

Comment: @Graviton: Also, don't get confused: iterators are NOT pointers, they were designed so that their use will closely relate that of pointers (you can perform basic *arithmetic* --depending on the type of iterator, you can dereference to assign or to read...), but in most cases the actual implementation differs. In particular `std::list<T>::iterator` can never be a pointer in a standard conforming implementation (while `std::vector<T>::iterator` could be a pointer in some implementation)

Answer (score 3):

The closest to what you want is not *pass-by-reference* but using pointers.

References both in Java and C# are more closely related to pointers than to C++ references: A reference in C++ is an alias to the object, equivalent to the `ref` keyword in C#, while a reference in C#/Java is an entity that refers (points) to the real instance (as a pointer in C/C++).

The following two are equivalent (assuming a struct type in C#):

```
void foo( type& param );     // c++
void foo( ref type param );  // c#
```

Now for reference types, the equivalent would be:

```
void foo( type* param );     // c++
void foo( type param );      // c#
```

With the difference that pointers in c++ are not automatically dereferenced, that is you have to use `operator->` instead of `.` to access members.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all C++ parameters are passed by value. Use `&` to indicate a reference.

Comment: I'm not even sure what this means, so it's hard to disagree. As far as C++ is considered, all variables (whether global or local to a function) could be in `malloc`ed memory instead of a data segment; there's no way you could tell anyway.

Comment: Downvoted this answer because firstly, the questioner clearly knows how to take a reference, and secondly, the question definitely does not ask about how to take a reference.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has different argument passing and assignment semantics. Whether something is passed by value, by reference, or by pointer, is not determined by its type. Argument passing and assignment is always explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no such type exists.

And (part of) the reason for this is that it just wouldn't make sense in C++. In C++, it makes a big difference whether an object is passed by value or reference, so the function *needs* to know how its parameter is passed.

In your code snippet, when implementing the first function, we *know* that we are given two references when the function is called: so any modification we make to these objects will be visible to the caller.

In the second function, we know that we are given two objects by value, meaning we can modify them freely, and that their destructors will be called at the end of the function.

If there was a sneaky type that broke this guarantee, and turned out to be a reference *anyway*, we could make our code blow up in all sorts of new and exciting ways.

Take a simple template function like this:

```
template <typename T>
T make_default() { return T(); }
```

If `T` is such a hypothetical "reference type", then this would be undefined behavior: it would create a local instance, and then return a *reference to it*. A reference to the object that just went out of scope and was deleted when the function returned.

Such reference types just don't really work well unless you have a garbage collector and throw away deterministic destruction, which is a pretty major C++ feature.

In C++, ownership is important. In order to write correct code, I need to know who owns every object. When is it created, when is it destroyed? A reference doesn't keep the object it points to alive, so if you're not careful, it can end up pointing to an object that no longer exists, as in my little template example above. We need to know whether or not the object we're working with is a reference.