# Allocate and initialize values for structs inside of a function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, struct, pass-by-reference

I want to use a function to allocate and initialize two related struct instances. However I can't get the memory to persist outside of the allocation function. Also, I'd rather do this without memory leaks if at all possible:

```
void alloc_init(foo_struct *bar, foo_struct *baz){
    //Create some values in here
    bar = new foo_struct(created_val1, created_val2);
    baz = new foo_struct(created_val3, created_val4);
}
```

If I check the value of `created_val1` in `bar` from within `alloc_init()` it's totally fine... But once `alloc_init` pops off the stack, I'm getting garbage. How do I make these kinds of values persist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the pointers by reference:

```
void alloc_init(foo_struct *& bar, foo_struct *& baz){
    //Create some values in here
    bar = new foo_struct(created_val1, created_val2);
    baz = new foo_struct(created_val3, created_val4);
}
```

Because you pass your pointers by value, you're allocating memory for *copies* of the original pointers inside the functions.

Comment: Oh, that's totally silly... It should pass pointers by reference by default! Why would you ever want to pass a pointer by value?

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher a pointer is a type, and you pass everything by value in C++ unless stated otherwise. It's not silly.

Comment: *"you pass everything by value in C++ unless.."* that is not true at all.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Is there ever a reason to pass a pointer by value though? I thought, for example, arrays were always passed by reference by default for this very reason.

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher arrays are not passed by reference, and moreover, they can't be reassigned.

Comment: @Als a more useful comment would have been a counter-example.

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher your confusion probably comes from the fact that you can modify the values of an array. That is true, but it still points to the same location. Just like in this case, if you modify the original `bar` or `baz`, the changes will persist outside the function.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore So you're saying you pass pointers by value so they can't be modified within the function? Aha, I guess that's totally obvious.

Comment: Counter example of a fundamentally flawed assumption is not warranted.The comment exactly says whats being wrongly spread as a generic rule in C++.

Comment: This topic is addressed directly in this question (apparently Luchian is correct): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724185/any-default-pass-by-reference-datatypes-in-c

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher what about it?

Comment: why is what wrong? My comment explicitly pointed out what is wrong, your generalization of a rule that one should pass everything by value in C++ is blatantly wrong.

Comment: @Als ah, ok I see the confusion. It wasn't a rule. What I meant was - In C++, everything is passed by value unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @Als the "unless stated otherwise" meant that you pass everything by values unless you explicitly pass it by reference.

Comment: If you have to explain a comment with two comments of double the size of the original comment i would believe the comment was badly worded enough to convey something(wrong) which perhaps it didn't mean to.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that I have to allocate everything within my function that I want to persist with `new` so it goes on the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher no. You can allocate in automatic storage (stack) and it can still persist outside the function call. You can for example return an object by value. Or you could pass objects, not pointers, by reference and assign to them inside the function. Neither of these use `new`, but extra copying *may* be involved.

Comment: @Als you're right, I could have chosen my wording most wisely. What's more important is that the op understood what I meant.

Comment: @FrancisW: When you don't want to change the value of the pointer itself, you pass it by value.

Comment: Thank you all for your insight. I'm used to working with garbage-collected languages like Haskell and Python, so I really appreciate your help with memory management.

Comment: @Als: FWIW, I found Luchian's original comment quite clear and your first two comments rather cryptic, so for at least one onlooker you  also had to explain your comment twice. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make them `static`, which isn't the greatest solution.  Or you can declare global variables at a higher scope, such as in a more-persistent class or global variable.

Comment: -1 terrible suggestion. What class? Why static? Why use globals when you don't need to?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  But it answers the question.  Which medicine is most appropriate to use is up to the engineer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really declare the variables at a higher scope, as the function itself is used to generate those values. I am however interested in why static variables would be useful here, if you could please elaborate.

Comment: No it doesn't. The memory persists outside the function scope anyway, since it's allocated in dynamic memory. However, the original pointers still won't point to it.